# Read .resx file names from a referenced assembly

Tags: c#, .net, assemblies, embedded-resource, resx

I want to retrieve the available resource files from a folder on a referenced assembly. I can access the assembly and get the names like this:

```
System.Reflection.Assembly assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(AppResources));
string[] names = assembly.GetManifestResourceNames();
```

But this doesn't give me the names I need, which are AppResources.resx, AppResources.en-US.resx, etc. How can I read those names?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You will find AppResources.resx in GetManifestResourceNames as

NamespaceOfAppResources . AppResources . resources

language specific resources are not located in the main assembly.

See handling assembly resources:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/Extracting_Embedded_Image.aspx